Why is my mouse cursor invisible in Windows 11?
Here is a video of the issue.
The mouse cursor is invisible, not gone but invisible. I can't see my mouse cursor anymore. When I move the mouse around I can see it highlighting things and clicking still works as expected, so I know the mouse is connected and working fine but the actual cursor is just invisible. I tried:

Changing the control panel mouse settings size.
Enabling pointer trails.
Changing the cursor style.
Restarting my machine.
Unpairing and pairing the mouse.
Using my mouse on another machine (works fine).
Using a different mouse (same issue).

If I play a game (like Call of Duty) which has it's own custom cursor it works fine, I can see it there. When I alt+tab so the game is running in the background with a window in the foreground I can see the Windows cursor when I'm hovering over the game window but when I move the cursor over a desktop window it disappears again. (You can see this in the video.)
I'm assuming I enabled some kind of feature by accident but I have no idea what brought this on.
The mouse works fine on other machines so my assumption is some kind of setting in Windows got enabled. Maybe some kind of touchscreen mode or accessibility feature, I have no clue.


Have you installed a tool to modify the cursor? Look in Task Manager / Details for any process that might be suspicious. 2. There are settings to auto-hide the mouse when typing: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/how-to-hide-cursor-while-typing.html Disable if set.


Nothing new has been installed when it happened and the auto-hide feature is not enabled

Ultimately I figured it out. I uninstalled AutoHotkey and the mouse came back. What's odd is I never added any scripts to AutoHotkey but for some reason it was the culprit here.
